# pandas gets the most dominant value in the column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to get the most dominant/the most frequent value of a column, so I tried the following code,

```
df['currency'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

which gives me, e.g.

```
USD    0.800000
CAD    0.100000
EUR    0.050000
GBP    0.050000
```

now the edge cases are like

```
USD    0.500000
CAD    0.500000
```

or

```
USD    0.333333
CAD    0.333333
CNY    0.333333
```

or

```
USD    0.400000
CAD    0.400000
CNY    0.100000
EUR    0.100000
```

and so on, where the frequencies are even among all values or part of the values.

Now I am trying to detect such edge cases so what is the best way to do that?

In other words, I am trying to find the most dominant frequency of some value in the series/column, in that `df['currency'].value_counts().max()` is not necessarily giving the most frequency, since the values given by `df['currency'].value_counts()` could all be the same. Hence `data.df['currency'].value_counts().idxmax()` won't necessarily give the index/column value having the higest frequency in the column.

Comment: You need `s = df[col].value_counts()`; `s[s==s.max()]`?

Comment: Did you consider using [Series.mode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [104]: df
Out[104]:
  currency
0      USD
1      USD
2      EUR
3      EUR
4      CAD

In [105]: df.currency.mode()
Out[105]:
0    EUR
1    USD
dtype: object

In [106]: len(df.currency.mode()) > 1
Out[106]: True
```

now let's "fix" our DF - by adding another row with `USD` currency, so there are NO "edge" cases any more:

```
In [107]: df.loc[len(df)] = ['USD']

In [108]: df
Out[108]:
  currency
0      USD
1      USD
2      EUR
3      EUR
4      CAD
5      USD

In [109]: len(df.currency.mode()) > 1
Out[109]: False

In [110]: df.currency.mode()
Out[110]:
0    USD
dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.loc[len(df)] = ['USD']` gave me `ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns`

Comment: @daiyue, that was just a demo - you shouldn't add rows to your DF... I just wanted to show the different output of `df.currency.mode()` when there are no "edge" cases...